# Games, Windows 8.1 and 144Hz display

Tags: windows-8.1, hdmi, dvi, gaming, refresh-rate

So I have been having problems with few games after switching from 7 to 8.1, which seems to be related to my 144Hz monitor.

Few examples: Shank, Shank 2, Blood of the Werewolf, Astebreed, the Sims 2 and Rayman Legends patch 1.2
Had few other as well but it's been long and I have 600+ steam library.

From those games at least the Sims 2 and Shank worked without any problems with same setup and Windows 7. So basically these games simply refuse to launch with basic setup. However if I plug 60Hz TV with HDMI instead everything magically starts to work. As for Astebreed and the Sims 2 using windowed mode seems to also work. As for Rayman Demo and version 1.0 works for some reason and 1.2 breaks settings menu.

I have already tried contacting supports. EA support stated game simply shouldn't work with 8.1 at all *(which is lie as it works with that TV and friend with 8 plays just fine)*, ubisoft support took few weeks and support said he will forward info for further processing, blood of the werewolf support had no idea what's going on and told me to just use my TV instead.
Changing monitors refresh rate to 120Hz or forcing it to 60Hz doesn't do anything. I have DVI right now but I will try with DisplayPort when I get the cable.

[At PCGW Garrett](http://community.pcgamingwiki.com/topic/1003-windows-8-and-144hz-display/?p=4459) said it may have something to do how listing resolutions work with 8 compared to earlier Windows versions but my googling skills don't bring anything up and compatibility mode for earlier windows version doesn't work either (not that I expected that to work).

My system specs are on [my steam profile](http://steamcommunity.com/id/marioysikax/).

How do I get those work with my 144Hz monitor as well as possible future games having same problem? Downgrading to 7 would work but is far from practical and I don't own legit lisence for that one.

Comment: OK I'm confused now. Switching from DVI to DisplayPort fixed the issue!